# PDFClown Hello World not working

Tags: java, pdfclown

I'm trying to run the first PDFClown java [example](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/common/contents/projects/clown/samples/HelloWorldSample.java)

but i'm unable to run it. Sample cannot be found, as well as the serialize method. Also, the run Overriding seems to have any sense at the moment. Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Anyway, check the user guide: http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/common/contents/projects/clown/doc/userGuide.pdf, chapter 3 "Installation"

Comment: uhm... it seems the link is broken..

Comment: try starting from http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/doc/index.html#User-Guide

Comment: Nice, but that page is almost empty. How should it fix the problem?

Comment: Come on, click on the first link "PDF Clown Project User Guide", it will open the PDF :)  Good luck

Comment: I solved, but i got runtime exceptions using the sample. Removed, i'll look for another one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the sample page (http://stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/samples/helloWorld.html), "This code sample is part of the downloadable PDF Clown distribution", so *you have to use it in the context of the distribution you can download from sourceforge* (https://sourceforge.net/projects/clown/).

Comment: Maybe this doesn't apply any more. What does "in the context of the distribution" mean?